# Can array_walk be nested in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I mean:

```
  array_walk($arr1,function(){
        //point 1
        array_walk($arr2,function(){
              //point 2
            });
    });
```

It seems this cannot work. the code just run in "point 1" and never run in "point 2".

is this a php bug?

thanks for all!

I find the reason, I have to use the "use(&$arr2)" in the first anonymos function defination, then the inner anonymos function can use this variables.

My php version is 5.6

Comment: but why would you do that??

Comment: Little hint: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php#refsect1-function.array-walk-parameters Look at the first note for the callback parameter

Comment: @Andrew just a nested loops

Comment: @Rizier123 yes, and I have find the reason, I must use "use" in the anonymos function defination, like this "use(&$arr2) ..."

Comment: @lovespring for nested loop, use array walk recursive

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array("1", "2");
$arr2 = array("22", "432");

/*
 * Specify the second walkway array as the
 * reference param of the callback function
 * if you want to manipulate it. Otherwise,
 * just pass $arr2.
 */
array_walk($arr1, function ($item1, $key, &$arr2) {

    // Point 1
    echo "$item1<br>";

    array_walk($arr2, function ($item2, $key1) {

        // Point 2
        echo "$item2<br>";

    });
}, $arr2); // Pass the other array to walk in within the walkway
```

This will print:

```
1
22
432
2
22
432
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @Amit.S thank you, Amit.S ! did you really check the $arr2 in the inner function ?

Comment: @lovespring sorry what you mean by check ?You need to pass the array to walk to the callback fn before you do array_walk. If it helped you the please accept the answer

Answer (score -1):

It works for this:

```
$arrayFirst = array(
        'ID'        => 1,
        'Name'      => 'First Array'
);
array_walk($arrayFirst, function () {
        echo "<pre>"; print_r("First Walk"); echo "</pre>";
        $arraySecond = array(
                'ID'        => 1,
                'Name'      => 'Second Array'
        );
        array_walk($arraySecond, function (){
            echo "<pre>"; print_r("Second Walk"); echo "</pre>";
        });
});
```